# Android: How can I check if a switch from another class is checked in a current class to perform other operations on it

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 4 fragments namely: `DashboardFragment.java`, `AlertsFragment.java`, `ManualControls.java` and `AutomatedControls.java`.
I have a switch in `ManualControls.java` which is used in the following code snippet:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual_controls, container, false);

        switchLED= (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.LEDSwitch1);
        switchLED.setChecked(false);
        switchLED.setTextOn("On");
        switchLED.setTextOff("Off");

//some codes about initializing a connection to my microcontroller to turn the LED on/off

 if(switchLED.isChecked()){
                        payload1="ledOn";
                    }

                    else{
                        payload1="ledOff";
                    }
```

Extra info:

*In the AlertsFragment.java, I have a dropdown spinner which has some values(sensor theresholds). A user selects a value from the dropdown, the value is compared with  sensor value received from cloud, then if a sensor value is greater than a sensor threshold selected in the spinner, an alert is raised.*

In `AlertsFragment.java` I want to raise the alarm if the switch from `ManualControls.java` is not checked. `switchLed` is the switch from `ManualControls.java`.

```
switchLED= (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.LEDSwitch1);

 if (!switchLED.isChecked()&&(ldrValue>spinnerValue)){
   //perform action
}
```

I want to know if this is correct way of doing it as I do not have my mob to test it right now and I am not sure if this approach is right.

Comment: where you are using those 4 fragments (in a single activity or non related)?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you meant. I suppose, it's a single activity as I am using a bottom navigation bar and those fragments are part of each navigation icon. The `MainActivity.java` file handles the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: try my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using in a single activity,

Declare a switch in your activity as

```
public Switch mySwitch;
```

In your fragments , you can initialise switch in *ManualControl.Java*

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).mySwitch= (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.LEDSwitch1);
```

Then access it in *AlertFragment.Java* as,

```
if (! ((YourActivity)getActivity()).mySwitch.isChecked()&&(ldrValue>spinnerValue)){
   //perform action
}
```

Be sure, when the switch is initialised. You can *check whether it is null and then perform action in AlertFragment*.

Comment: Then I should add its properties in the `mainactivity.xml`, right? The thing is that it then disrupts my bottom navigation bar layout by making a switch appear there.

Comment: No, You just declare an object in your activity.

Comment: Thanks, I got it :) Will let you know if it works(pretty sure it does though ;) )

Comment: If it worked, please accept my answer. Or else post errors what you got

Comment: Sure, once I test it on a mob app I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you, wish you the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using that four fragment in same activity then put switch object in activity and initialise properly, So you can access switch position in all four fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean, in my `MainActivity.java`, I initialize the switch as such `private switch switchLed;` and `switchLED= (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.LEDSwitch1);` so that in my fragments I can use `switchLed`?

Comment: The switch then appears on my main activity and disrupt my bottom navigation bar layout.